# "I am not sure if/that it will last"

Tags: differences

> I am not sure **if** it will last
>
> I am not sure **that** it will last
>
> I am not sure it will last

What is the difference between these sentences?

Comment: They are equivalent.

Comment: Nothing much to chose between them. You might also have said *Not sure whether it will last*.

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether) gives part of the answer: I doubt if, I don’t know whether
We use if or whether to introduce clauses after verbs of doubting:

I don’t know if I can drive. My foot really hurts.

I didn’t prune the rose bush this year so I doubt if we’re going to have many flowers. (‘prune’ means cut back)

We’ll have plenty of photographs to show you but I’m not sure whether we’ll be able to learn very much from them.